# What is $T(p(a x^2+b))$ when $T(p(x))=x^2p'(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be linear transformation on $\mathbb{P} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}$ that $T(p(x))=x^2p'(x)$.

1. Then, what is the value of $T(p(ax^2+b))$?

I think it could be $x^2p'(ax^2+b)$ or $2ax^3p'(ax^2+b)$ or even something else.

2. What would be the result when $T$ is on $\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$? ($\mathbb{D}$ is set of differentiable functions)

Comment: Can you please say what is $\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{D}$ is a set of differentiable function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T(p(ax^{2}+b))=x^{2} \frac  d {dx} (p(ax^{2}+b))=x^{2}p'(ax^{2}+b) (2ax)$ by Chain Rule. The answer is same for $\mathbb D$.

Comment: Why not $T(p(ax^2+b)) = (ax^2+b)^2\cdot (2ax) \cdot p'(ax^2+b)$?

Comment: $Tf(x)=x^{2}f'(x)$. You always multiply by $x^{2}$ whatever  $f$ is. @VIVID

Comment: @VIVID your operation is not linear

Comment: @MoreAnonymous Yes, I already got that :)